# Can every request send by ajax (xmlhttprequest) be called as web service request?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I just started using angularjs with spring mvc as backend. I am using `$resource` for accessing my backend. I know this is a rest service and `$resource` is a module built with ajax. My doubts:

1) Is ajax used for consuming web service apis only?
2) Is ajax the only way to call web service function?

Comment: Quick answers: 1) no 2) no

Comment: Java or JavaScript? I'm assuming JavaScript but the answer is pretty much the same either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) *Is ajax used for consuming web service apis only*

No, ajax is just a way of making HTTP/HTTPS requests, they can request anything that accepts such a request, **but** it is most commonly used for consuming web services/APIs.

---

2) *Is ajax the only way to call web service function*

No, again, webservices are usually just exposing an endpoint for data, anything capable of making a HTTP/HTTPS request can call it, for example you can type http://www.mywebservice.com/api/get/1 in your browser and you will make a call to the web service and the data would be displayed in the browser.